# заполнение html формы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так,чтоб в форме обратной связи в поле "Номер телефона" код оператора был статичным, и при заполнении определенного количества символов между ними появлялся дефис как в примере ниже 
[image: пример 1]

[image: пример 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть несколько методов, вы можете использовать простой метод, Phone number mask, почитайте [на Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/37249/), может помочь.

Comment: Спасибо, все отлично работает)

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста )

Comment: желательно добавить текстовое описание решения проблемы, ибо ссылка со временем может стать невалидной

Comment: @lexxl, хорошо, позже допишу примеры